# How do I convert my python project into exe that has opencv and Numpy

Tags: python

I want to convert a piece of code into an exe file. I tried using `py2exe` and `auto-py-tp-exe` but I'm facing difficulties while doing so.

This is for my college project and I'm kind of a noob. So if anyone could help me with the exe part, it would be great for me.

Comment: Look up `pyinstaller`. It is super easy (`pyinstaller myfile.py`), but can do some neat stuff as well, like bundling everything into one file. It _does_ have... issues sometimes handling files that aren't just the source, such as images or config files. But if you just have one source file, I'd use `pyinstaller`

Comment: refer [this documentation](https://datatofish.com/executable-pyinstaller/).

Comment: @cocomac I tried using pyinstaller too. I can convert single script files, but I just don't know how to do it when packages such as cv2, opencv , numpy have been used

Comment: Pyinstaller will just bundle the modules together i think. Pyinstaller has support `numpy` and other big modules such as `PyQt5`, `matplotlib`. Even if open-cv is not included it will still work. To turn it into an exe first in command prompt change to current directory of project so `cd path\to\directory` then do `pyinstaller my_script.py` if you want the application to not have a console and to be one file do `pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole my_script.py` here is a link to [pyinstaller docs](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/)